# Can't seem to get 404 page working

Tags: .htaccess

First of this is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I've got that working but when I go to a page like example:

```
localhost/test
```

it loads the same page but shows no content.

```
localhost/test
```

is not on my server and I can't seem to get the 404 to work I've tried everything for the past 3 days

I've lost the code for the 404 in the htacces as my computer crashed

What I'm Trying to do is bring up the 404 when there isn't an id from the database so when people go to an invalid link there will be a 404 page

Comment: If you want to redirect to a 404 as a result of processing a page like `index.php` then use the `header` function within the PHP page itself to redirect to the 404 when the id isn't found.

Comment: You ask Apache to redirect *everything* to `index.php`. Where do you expect a "Not Found" error to come from?

Comment: How can i change it to so index.php?id=$1 redirects to localhost/$1 and have the 404 working aswell?

Comment: you have to handle the nothing found condition in the gateway (index.php) script.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following code to the beginning of your `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Then create a new file `404.php` at the root of your website. This file will be displayed when the user tries to access a URL that does not match an existing file and is not handled by your Rewrite rules.

Comment: I've done that still isn't working if it would help i can provide screen shots from gyazo to show what is exactly happening and my rewrite mod is turned on in wamp

Comment: won't work because of the rewrite ... apache will always find a endpoint for the request.

Answer (score 0):

in your index.php you are doing a lookup based on the path in the url or some other variable. If you get a no match just respond with a

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

followed by the output you want on your error document.